# Array of fixed length strings in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'd like to have an array of fixed length strings in c in the form of a pointer so I can dynamically allocate the memory for it.
I can see plenty of reference to arrays of pointers to string, but not to what I want to achieve.

What I want is to be able to declare a pointer to char[MAX_STRING_LENGTH] so I can then dynamically allocate a contiguous block of memory for all the strings:

```
char *(names[MAX_STRING_LENGTH]);  // This won't work
names = (some cast)malloc(NUM_STRINGS * MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
```

And then access the array of strings:

```
strcpy(name, names[stringIndex]);
```

How do I declare the variable and cast the pointer from malloc?

Comment: So if i follow you, you want to have a big char array so you can do your own allocation inside of it?

Comment: I want to do a single allocation of a two-dimensional array where the second dimension is fixed

Comment: "length" of a _string_ usually does not include is _null character_.   Consider `strlen()`.  Code may need `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` --> `MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1` to use `names` correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declare `names` as an array of pointers, not a pointer to arrays. That would be

```
char (*names)[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];  // Names is a pointer to an array of char
```

Now you can allocate memory for the pointer:

```
// Allocate memory for NUM_STRINGS arrays and assign the pointer to names
names = malloc(NUM_STRINGS * sizeof *names);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but stumbled upon the cast from malloc. How would you do such cast?

Comment: @Dan [In C you don't need to cast the return from `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (and probably shouldn't).

Comment: Can one omit parentheses around *names in declaration?

Comment: @PaulDydyshko No. `char (*names)[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];` defines a pointer to an array of `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` characters. But `char *names[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];` defines an array of `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` *pointers* to characters. The first is a pointer to an array, the second is an array of pointers. Very big difference. :)

Answer (score 2):

You want a pointer to array `MAX_LENGTH` of `char` Using `cdecl` (note that cdecl doesn't understand things like `MAX_LENGTH` so we use a number here instead):

```
% cdecl
Type `help' or `?' for help
cdecl> declare names as pointer to array 256 of char;
char (*names)[256]
```

we get that the proper declaration is

```
char (*names)[MAX_LENGTH];
```

However this still isn't very useful, because `realloc`ation would be very costly because it possibly could have to move each and every string to a new location. So I suggest that you'd still use a *pointer to pointer to char*.

Answer (score 1):

Someprogrammerdude already provided the solution.

Generally, since C/C++ types can become somewhat tricky, you can utilize any half-decent IDE to look up correct type definitions.

This trick relies on the C++11 `auto` keyword, which determines a variable type from its initializer. The resulting type can still be used in other C/C++ versions and is not restricted to C++11.

In your case, specify a type that you know and that can be transformed into the type you want:

```
char names[10][10];
```

Then assign an `auto` variable with the desired type:

```
auto names2 = &names[0];
```

Inspect the actual type of `names2` and use it. For example, in Visual Studio, just hover the mouse over `names2` to see the type. Most IDEs will display the type by hovering over either the `auto` keyword or the defined variable.

For the example, hovering would reveal the type `char (*names2)[10]`.

Comment: `auto names2 = &names[0];` --> _warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'names2'_ and will certainly not work with this C post.  Perhaps you are coding in another language?

Comment: @chux oh damn it, I guess I fell for the VS C is not really C trap again... it's C++11 `auto` and I'll have to update my answer. The result of this type-check can still be applied to C/C++ though

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concept of Pointer Arrays.Refer the book "The C programming Language" By Dennis M. Ritchie & Kernighan. Specially the pointer and array part.There are some amazing stuffs to read. Probably you will get a more deeper concept of pointers and arrays after reading and solving some problems given in the book.